# Printing console messages in a output window on HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently working on a graph application using d3.js. Following is the link to the d3-forced directed graph:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045
If i create an on-click event for a node like:

```
node.on("click", function(d){
           console.log(d.id);
                         });
```

This even will print the names of nodes in the console of the developers tools of the browser. However I need to create a window in the html page(a widget) which will take this value and print it on clicking the node.

Is there any way to print the console output on html window widget(just another div)?

P.S. there is a similar question asked: how to make a output console using TextArea? But the answer is for determining the thresholding and not how to create it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: `$('#somediv').append('<p>' + d.id + '</p>');` instead of console.log(), basically.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening a new window via javascript.

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write(d.id);
```

Comment: I got it what you are trying to say. However, i want to create a console like application, similar to regular consoles which will print the events in the d3 graph. I tried using dialogue in HTML, but the dimensions and appearance is too bad, maybe i can change it later, however, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Omkar -- you can try using some js plugins like this one - http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the page directly, in javascript you can use :

```
document.getElementById();
```

and there are a lot of different selectors you can see on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

Then to modify the HTML you only have to do like this :

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "test";
```

PS : if you use jquery you can use the $ function like this for example to do the same :

```
$("#example").html("test");
```

It uses the css selector so # means id.

Comment: Thanks Colas, this helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Like lynko said you can override console.log:

```
console.log = function (message) {
    //prettify message here
    $("#console_out_div").append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
};

console.log("test123");
console.log([1,3,4]);
console.log({a:"test", b: 2});
```

You just have to check the `instanceof` and `typeof` variable `message` and prettify the output. Something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwjtLejs/).

Answer (score 0):

It's kludgey, but you could write `console.log = customLogFunc;` at the top of your script.